# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js'

Tags: npm

I am trying to install ng-mqtt, but I keep getting that error for the post-install.

I tried to run "npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular"
I wonder how can i get this file ( '../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js')

here in the output when I run npm I ngx-mqtt

```
> ngx-mqtt@8.0.3 postinstall /home/duma/Documents/Alala/SmartHome/node_modules/ngx-mqtt
> node postinstall

{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   '../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js' }
/home/duma/Documents/Alala/SmartHome/node_modules/ngx-mqtt/postinstall.js:33
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js'
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7 requires a peer of typescript@~4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.9 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.0 <4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@11.0.7 requires a peer of typescript@~4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mqtt@8.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mqtt@8.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngx-mqtt@8.0.3 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ngx-mqtt@8.0.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/duma/.npm/_logs/2021-01-15T20_01_23_708Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please share your package.json. Looks like you need `"typescript": "~4.0.0" `  in your devDependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had an problem just like yours and this solved it for me.

npm install git+https://github.com/angular/angular-devkit-build-angular-builds.git

Hope it helps you too :)